# Swift 'String.Type' does not have a member named 'stringWithContentsOfFile'

Tags: swift

I am having trouble to read text string from .text file in Swift.

I could manage to write file using following code

```
var writeError: NSError?
let theFileToBeWritten = theStringWillBeSaved.writeToFile(pathToTheFile, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &writeError);
```

But whenever I try to read the file using "String.stringWithContentsOfFile", I get "'String.Type' does not have a member named 'stringWithContentsOfFile'". stringWithContentsOfFile also does not appear in autocomplete.

I am using Xcode 6.1 GM Seed 2.

I have seen people using "stringWithContentsOfFile" to read text from file in many tutorials and stack overflow but why is it not working for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var error:NSError?
let string = String(contentsOfFile: "/usr/temp.txt", encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
if let theError = error {
   print("\(theError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Swift 2.2:

```
if let string = try? String(contentsOfFile: "/usr/temp.txt") {
  // Do something with string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with correct syntax. I am not sure why Apple did not update their documentation here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:

Or i am looking at wrong documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Correct syntax in swift for String contentsOfFile is:

```
String(contentsOfFile: "String", encoding: "NSStringEncoding", error: "NSErrorPointer")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
var error : NSError?
var myFileContent = String()
myFileContent = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile("yourFilePath", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
if let optionalError = error{
    println("\(optionalError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavi, this syntax is not correct for Swift in Xcode 6.1. May be it was in Xcode 6.

Comment: @moinuddin thanks for the reply brother what is the error that you are getting as I am successfully able to run and print myFileContent and yes I am working on Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: stringWithContentsOfFile is unavailable: use object construction NSString(contentsOfFile:encoding:error:)